# Can somebody explain the difference between **param and *param in C using a visual diagram?

Tags: c

In particular, why changes to parameters like `*param` aren't propagated back to the caller of a function but changes to parameters like `**param` do propagate back?

Comment: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/12/c-pointers-fundamentals/

Comment: Can you post some example code depicting what you are seeing?

Comment: The question presumes a false premise. Please specify a code example that confuses you or doesn't do what you expect it to do, so that someone can provide a meaningful answer.

Comment: Please improve your question: [what have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`int param` is a variable, i.e. data.

`int * param` is *a pointer to* a variable, i.e. the memory address of data.

`int * * param` is *a pointer to* a pointer to a variable, i.e. the memory address of a memory address of data.

And so on.

When a function is called with a variable as argument, that argument gets *copied* to the stack (call-by-value). Any changes that the function does on its parameter is actually done on the copy, which gets destroyed with the rest of the stack frame when the function returns.

```
void foo( int x )
{
    x = 23;     // any changes done on x are strictly local
}

int main()
{
    int a = 42;
    foo( a );   // no matter what foo() does, a will still be 42.
    return 0;
}
```

If you pass *a pointer to* a variable as argument to a function, it likewise gets copied - but the copy of a memory address still points to the same memory address, so the function can *access* that memory address (i.e., the original variable, not its copy on the stack). Changes that the function does on the contents of that memory address affect the function's caller.

```
void foo( int * x )
{
    *x = 23;     // changing the contents of the memory address pointed to by x
}

int main()
{
    int a = 42;
    foo( &a );   // passing the address of a; a will be changed to 23.
    return 0;
}
```

You should be able to take it from there yourself.

Answer (score 2):

In both the cases the changes will be propagated but it depends on calling function.

see the case below (Since you have not given any code so, I am assuming a general scenario)

Famous swap function

```
int a=5,b=10;
swap(&a,&b) // Calling by address

void swap(int *paramA,int *paramB)
{ 
// Do the swap
}
```

You see that even in the function definition only `*params` but changes is reflected back to calling environment.

But in other case `*param` may not reflect when it is passed by value, means,

see this code ,

```
int a;
int *p = &a;


foo(p); // calling by value

void foo(int *param)
{
 // if you do anything or change param to point to some other memory location
 // then it will not be reflected back and p still be pointing to a.
}
```

while if you do this

```
foo(&p); //calling 

void foo(int **param)
{
 // if you do anything or change param to point to some other memory location
 // then it must be reflected back in calling environment.
}
```

These things are called `Pass by value` and `Pass by Address` in `C` when calling functions.

I hope you got it.